# aggregate on string in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code :

```
string[] curries = { "abc", "ab", "abcd" };
var c = curries.Aggregate<string,string,int>("Some curries ",(a,b)=>a +" " +b,a=>a.Length);

Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Output is 25. Can anybody explain this please?

Comment: Well, what did you expect, and why? 25 is the length of "Some curries abc ab abcd".

Comment: have you read the docs for Aggregate()? it's all stated really clearly there.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Learning purpose...

Comment: But before asking, what research did you perform? It's still not clear which part of this you're confused about, or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aggregate(IEnumerable, Func) method makes it simple to perform a calculation over a sequence of values. This method works by calling func one time for each element in source. Each time func is called, Aggregate(IEnumerable, Func) passes both the element from the sequence and an aggregated value (as the first argument to func). The first element of source is used as the initial aggregate value. The result of func replaces the previous aggregated value. Aggregate(IEnumerable, Func) returns the final result of func.

Thus "Some curries ", "abc" ,"ab", "abcd" and 3 spaces " " are concatenated. So total length becomes 25.

Comment: this example uses Aggregate(IEnumerable, Func, Func) though, which I believe is the source of confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is same as the below.

```
string[] curries = { "abc", "ab", "abcd" };
string x = "Some curries ";
foreach (var curry in curries)
{
   x = x + " " + curry;
}
var c = x.Length;
```

I think the code is self explantory !

After the foreach loop `x` variable will have a string `"Some curries  abc ab abcd"` which has length 25

Comment: int[] numbers = { 9, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1, 8 };
       var query = numbers.Aggregate(5, (a,b) => ( (a < b) ? (a * b) : a));can you please tell me how this works also? It shows result to be 45 but i assumed it be 15120

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Just appending the string with the curries?  Assuming that is what you want, the following aggregate function works.

```
var c = curries.Aggregate("Some curries", (current, str) => current + (" " + str));
```

If you want the length of the string, you can just check the length of the aggregated string.